# Unable to download Xcode crash reports

Tags: xcode

I am unable to download the latest crash reports in Xcode Organizer. I see the following error message :
An error occurred preventing Xcode from downloading crashes list. "xxxxx" failed with error: Waiting for future 'CrashPointNetworkListSource' to complete timed out
I am using Xcode 13.2.1. Anybody have an idea how I could fix this?

Comment: are you behind a firewal?

Comment: No. To clarify,  the error messages is shown sporadically. Sometimes it is able to download crash reports and sometimes they are missing.